# Gradient Color for Dynamic Text in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to show some dynamic text in Gradient Color in SSRS. Can anyone suggests how to achieve this. This dynamic text will be coming from Fetch XML query.

[Gradient Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYtOP.jpg)This is how I need to show my dynamic text in SSRS report after downloading into PDF.

Regards,
kiran P

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is not possibly with SSRS.